# Angles for a great dodecahedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry

Could someone describe to me how to find the angle between two intersecting pentagonal faces on a great dodecahedron?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't a great dodecahedron have triangular faces?  A regular dodecahedron has pentagonal faces...

Comment: There is an illustrative discussion of a comment similar to that of @mjqxxxx above in *Proofs and refutations* by Imre Lakatos on pp. 16--17 and pp. 30--33.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is $$\arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \approx 63^\circ 26' 06'' \approx 1.107148718 \; \mbox{radians} $$ and thereby precisely supplementary to the dihedral angles of the ordinary dodecahedron.

The three books I have on this sort of thing are *Platonic and Archimedean Solids* by Daud Sutton, *Shapes, Space, and Symmetry* by Alan Holden, and *Regular Polytopes* by H. S. M. Coxeter. Sutton gives angles in degree-minute-second format, while Coxeter shows how to find them on pages 20-22.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_dodecahedron